# Hiding entire Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, visibility

Is there a way to hide an entire Crystal Report Viewer (print preview / .rpt) when the user logs out of the application and unhide it once the user logs back in? It was created on a different thread using the following code and FormReportViewer  is a Crystal Report Viewer.

```
<STAThread()>
Private Sub Rpt1()
    Dim f1 as FormReportViewer = New FormReportViewer 
    rptName = rptPath & "ReportName.rpt"
    f1.Text = "Report"
    f1.Tag = rptName
    Application.Run(f1)
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: you are not mention that it is for window application or web application. But I think you tell about web app, so in above code before Dim statement you need to check the session variable  as " if(session variable = 0) then login", please check how to set and get session variable  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437741/using-session-to-get-set-object-properties-everytime

Comment: I'm sorry it is a windows application

Comment: Ok, so why are you think that after login user is logout. Its very easy in window app, you just hide the menu when user logout, i.e. user can not access the menu and unable to generate the report simple.

Comment: Thank you, maybe I wasn't clear. I was trying to hide open Crystal Report Viewers where new instances were created on different threads. Everything except the CRV's were hiding. I was however able to get them to hide and show as a user logs in and out.

Comment: In this case, you may pass the session variable (forgot for window) or a variable to the above method that identifies that user is log-in, so after getting the user log-in detail, just required an if condition.